# How to store jtable value in databse

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I am developing a project about a hotel management system. I have a two forms, checkin and service allocation form, written in Netbeans. In the checkin form I will simply enter the values of customer details. I am using an ms-access database.

In the database I have a service field that I leave blank while entering the checkin form.

Next is the service allocation form. In this form I have one textfield and one jtable. Every time I enter in textfield and click add button it adds to jtable. I want to store all the values of the jtable in the service field in the database which has a column numbered 5.

This is my code:

```
int row=jTable1.getRowCount();
for(int i=0;i<=row;i++)
{
    service1=jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).toString();
    System.out.println(service1);
    System.out.println("here checked");  
    ps.setString(15,service1);
}
```

I have only one column in the jtable. I have store the value but it is giving this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your backstory is relevant to your question, but you are probably getting an off-by-one error in your loop. Try this:

```
int row = jTable1.getRowCount();
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    service1=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
    System.out.println(service1);
    System.out.println("here checked");  
    ps.setString(15, service1);
}
```

As a general rule, loops should start at `0` and should be tested with `i < length`.